# changing image based on dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

Sorry i'm a new to php & jquery

How do i change images based on dropdown menu code below using jquery

```
 echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "    <label for='image'>  Select Image File :</label>
<select name='image' class='form-control'>
 <option value=''>Select Image </option>";

 foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $image){
       $image = basename($image);
       echo "<option value='" . $image . "'>".$image."</option>";
    }



echo "</select></div>";


 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#image :selected").text(); // The text content of the selected option
$("#image").val(); // The value of the selected option

});
</script>

echo "<img src='images/$image'<br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 echo "<div class='form-group'>";
 echo "<label for='image'>  Select Image File :</label>
 <select name='image' id='selectsrc' class='form-control'>
   <option value=''>Select Image </option>";
   foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $image){
       $image = basename($image);
       echo "<option value='" . $image . "'>".$image."</option>";
   }

 echo "</select></div>";
 echo '<img src="images/example.jpg" id="changesrc">';

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#selectsrc').change(function(){
         $("#changesrc").attr('src',$(this).val());
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: How do i prevent other select in my form effect this code .. i tried something like this $('select#name').change(function(){   but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "    <label for='image'>  Select Image File :</label>
<select name='image' class='form-control' id=
'image'>
 <option value=''>Select Image </option>";

 foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $key => $image){
       $image = basename($image);
       echo "<option data-img-src='".$image."' value='".$key. "'>".$image."</option>";
 }



echo "</select></div>";
```

After that your change can be, for example:

```
$('#image').change(function () {
    $('img').attr("src", $( this ).find( "option:selected" ).data( "img-src" ));
});
```